# Internet Explorer - CSS box-Shadow around container div only

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Here is my css for my site.  The box-shadows work perfectly for chrome and firefox, but I can not get this to work correctly for internet explorer 9 and below.  It does work correctly on IE 10.  I would like the box-shadow to only wrap around the container div.  Don't really care if the box-shadow works around the topleft div, but if thats a easy fix feel free to help with that too.  Thank you for your time.

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
background-color: #FFF;
}
html {
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
overflow-y: scroll;
}
#container {
width: 1000px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 0px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 0px #000;
/* For IE 8 */
/* -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=0)";*/
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=90)";
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=180)";
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=270)";
/* for IE 5.5 - 7 */
 filter:
   /* progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=0, Color='#cccccc'),*/
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=90, Color='#cccccc'),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=180, Color='#cccccc'),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=270, Color='#cccccc');
}

#container #topbox {
padding:0;
margin:0;
height: 35px;
width: 1000px;
}
#container #topnav {
height: 35px;
width: 750px;
float:left;
}
#container #cse
{
height: 20px;
width: 250px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 15px;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-top: -10px;
}

#container #Topleft {
height: 200px;
width: 250px;
border: 5px solid #EAEAEA;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
-moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
-ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);  /* IE 9 */
-o-transform: rotate(-2deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
transform: rotate(-2deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 0px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 0px #000;
background-color: #FFF;
}
#container #TopRight {
height: 150px;
width: 740px;
}
#container #banner {
height: 100px;
width: 670px;
padding-left: 70px;

}
#container #alertmessage {
height: 50px;
width: 740px;
background-color: #006;
}
#alertmessagebox {
width: 730px;
height: 45px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 1em;
color: #CCC;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
/*display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;*/
}
#container #SideNav {
width: 260px;

}
#container #leftcol {
float: left;
padding-bottom: 150px;
/*background-color: #FFF;*/
}
#container #rightcol {
float: left;
}
#container #Body {
width: 740px;
height: auto;
background-color: #33F;
}
#container #Footer {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #006;
width: 1000px;
clear: both;
color: #CCC;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: With no HTML, this will be pretty hard, if not impossible, to debug. Please consider making a jsfiddle demo, including the HTML and the CSS needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: here is the website.  http://www.rsd17.org/test/test/untitled1.shtml.  I will try and make a jsfiddle tomorrow for you.  thanks for looking at this issue.

Comment: For IE9 the filter is obscuring the box-shadow. If you remove that it works fine. I would remove the filter from the style sheet, and only give it to IE8 and below using a conditional comment. As for IE8 and below, they don't support box-shadow.

Comment: After looking at the filter more closely, I've found the issue with it. I'll supply an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9 correctly supports box-shadow, but the filter is interfering with it. The Filter is actually working correctly, but not where you expect. You will notice that it is adding a filter around the child elements. This is because it is a drop shadow, and the background of your container is transparent. You can fix it by adding a background-color to the container div:

```
#container { background-color: white; }
```

Comment: awesome that almost got it perfect.  just one problem.  If I comment out this line, in ie9 i don't get a right side, but looks perfect in 8.  but if I leave it in i get an top bar on my search box on ie8 and ie9 looks perfect. progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=0, Color='#cccccc'), anyway to fix this so it works for both?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't see where you use that code.

Comment: its located in my css under my #container div with all my box-shadow things.  if you look above its commented out.  I uncommented it to work in IE9, but in ie8 there is a top border around my google search only.

Comment: It is difficult to test without a test case, especially with commented out code that doesn't show in the debugger. I'd suggest playing around with the direction of the filter or seeing what is causing the gap at the top of the page, such as a top margin or elements that could be pushing it down a touch.